# Why can I no longer access my WordPress admin page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to migrate my website from one domain to another, so I used WordPress move plugin. While using WordPress move plugin I used change domain option, made the required changes, but after that, I am not able to access my website from old domain or new domain even I cant access admin dashboard.

How can I get at admin panel so I can revert the changes?

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: [help], then read: [MCVE] and: [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access your db in order to see the domain name in the wp_options table, the plugin you used might changed that.
You can see your site domain in wp_options under 'siteurl', it tops the table rows.

In order to access your db you need to connect to your hosting panel (cpanel, plesk etc) and open phpMyAdmin.

Then you can achive a full domain change in db ( domain might be found in more tables than just wp_options ) you need to use a

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Just upload it to your new hosting and access it via browser.

For example if you upload a folder containing the above script name search_and_replace, you can access it hitting domain.com/search_and_replace

Then just place your old domain in the left input and the new domain in the right one and hit live run.

Just be cautious and be aware that this script is performing db changes so if anything goes wrong you need to have a db backup.

When the script completes execution you need to access your sites wp-admin and resave the permalinks in order for wordpress to create the new .htaccess

Comment: thank you for your reply, got that problem solved, then i migrated my site manually, I almost completed,the migration but the problem is only home page is working fine no other links to other pages working,its giving error 500, if clicked on other pages,would you suggest me what other changes do i need to makeso that all the pages work fine. instead of search and replace tool from github, i manually replaced domain name from databases using np++,and then uploaded that database.

Comment: I've suggested to use the toll mentioned above for complete search-and-replace. I've also told you to resave the permalinks from the admin panel, done that already?

Comment: yes i did that, problem is resoloved , thank you once again